# identify duplicates as well as the matched unique record in oracle

Tags: oracle, duplicates

hi i am running the follwoing query to identify the duplicate records.

```
SELECT *
          FROM unique2 P WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM unique2 C 
                                    WHERE ( (C.surname) =  (P.surname)) 
                                      AND ( (C.postcode) =  (P.postcode)) 
                                      AND ((( (C.forename) IS NULL OR  (P.forename) IS NULL) 
                                      AND  (C.initials) =  (P.initials)) 
                                        OR  (C.forename) =  (P.forename))
                                      AND ( (C.sex) =  (P.sex) 
                                        OR  (C.title) =  (P.title)) 
                                      AND (( (C.address1))=( (P.address1)) 
                                        OR ( (C.address1))=( (P.address2)) 
                                        OR ( (C.address2))=( (P.address1))
                                        OR  instr(C.address1_notrim, P.address1_notrim) > 0 
                                        OR  instr(P.address1_notrim, C.address1_notrim) > 0)
                                      AND C.rowid < P.rowid);
```

But with this query i can't identify the unique record id which is matched to the duplicate records. Is there a way to identify the 
duplicates as well as the unique record id(my table has unique key) to which those duplicates are matched?

Answer (score 1):

```
select id
from promolog
where surname, postcode, dob in (
  select surname, postcode,dob
  from (
    select surname, postcode, dob, count(1)
    from promolog
    group by surname,postcode,dob
    having count(1) > 1
  )
)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. but i have some other rules to identify the duplicates which are like:                          a. DOB AND
b. Postcode AND
c. Surname AND
d. Address
i. mailed_address1 = mailed_address1
ii. Or mailed_address1 = mailed_address2
iii. Or mailed_address2 = mailed_address1
iv. Or mailed_address1 of record1 in mailed_address1 of record2
v. Or mailed_address1 of record2  in mailed_address1 of record1

Comment: @subash just add/change whatever fields you need to compare in this query (I used 3 fields from your original post: surname, postcode, dob).

Comment: @subash:Its will be better ,if you update your question .And what problem are you getting.

Comment: @subash like I said, use this as a template of what to do, add to or modify the combination of fields you think SHOULD be unique

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this with analytic functions:

```
select id, num_of_ids, first_id, surname, postcode, dob
from (
    select id,
        count(*) over (partition by surname, postcode, dob) as num_of_ids,
        first_value(id)
            over (partition by surname, postcode, dob order by id) as first_id,
        surname,
        postcode,
        dob
    from promolog
)
where num_of_ids > 1;
```

---

Based on your update, I think you can just do a self-join, which you can make as complicated as you like:

```
select dup.*, master.id as duplicate_of
from promolog dup
join promolog master
on master.surname = dup.surname
and master.postcode = dup.postcode
and master.dob = dup.dob
... and <address checks etc. > ...
and master.rowid < dup.rowid;
```

But maybe I'm still missing something. As the name suggests, `exists` is for testing the existence of a matching record; if you want to retrieve any of the data from the matched record then you'll need to join to it at some point.